# Generate Zend Framework PDF doc's from HTML

Tags: zend-framework, pdf, pdf-generation, mpdf

I want to generate zend framerwork's documentation to PDF from HTML so I can print it. I use mPDF library to achieve my target. PDF are generated normally. But the thing is that I don't know how to insert page breaks automatically, because now page are generated as is. Means If page is about 1,5 or 2 A4 pages then it would be printed as a whole, without page breaks. This is bad, because I can't print it.
What should I do?

Comment: If you need a Zend Framework 2 module based on Snappy PHP (5.3+) wrapper for the wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltoimage conversion utility take a look to [MvlabsSnappy](https://github.com/mvlabs/MvlabsSnappy) .

Answer (score 1):

The css style `page-break-after: always;` might be what you're looking for.  Not sure if that is supported in mPDF.

I use [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) to convert html to pdf. It runs on WebKit (What Safari and Chrome use), so it supports tons of CSS properties.

Comment: Thanks for your post, but mpdf suits less or more. I need to have converter as web-service or web-application, not desktop application or utility.

Comment: Did page-break-after solve your issue?

Sorry, I wasn't clear.  It's running on a webserver. wkhtmltopdf is called from PHP and I get a nice CSS3 formatted PDF.